# Variable doesn't initialize in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I am working on a JSP page with certain areas visible and others not (I'll also be checking on the pages these sections link to for authentication/authorization). For some reason the third string that I create does not seem to be created. You can see in the debug image that I am past the line where the variables are created and the String still does not exist. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding amongst other things.

```
<% 
    boolean invalidLogin = false;
    try {
        invalidLogin = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("invalid"));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    String logOnAreaVisibility = " display:none; ";
    String logOffAreaVisibility = " display:none; ";
    String adminAreaVisibility = " display:none; ";
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: A couple thoughts for you. First the IDE is putting a squiggle under adminAreaVisibility. This usually suggests that the variable is never used. So first thing is to check that the variable is actually used later in the code. Second in my experience, Tomcat and some containers maintain a "cache" directory. Sometimes I've needed to clear out that cache directory to refresh the code base. My guess is that the IDE is telling you that you are not using that variable and the variable might not be created by the compiler as an optimization.

Comment: this was exactly it. I changed the value at other points in my code but accidentally used a different variable name for output instead. Thank you!